Is there a way to get my old Mac to run its old software faster?
In order to use an application (Pages '09) that doesn't work on newer computers, I'm using a 2011 Macbook Air running OS 10.13.6 (High Sierra). I haven't installed any new software on it since I stopped using it, but even running its old software the computer is incredibly slow--much slower, I feel, than when I was using it for my main computer.
Is there a way to get it to be even a little less slow? Because I have to use this app for a project and doing it at this pace is going to drive me crazy. I'm happy to wipe the computer or reformat it or whatever if that will help. (I have the iWork software on a separate install USB.) I'm also happy to run the computer not connected to the Internet.
Thanks so much in advance for any help anybody can give me.

Test if the software runs faster on a newer Mac (or even Linux or Windows PC!) using a virtual machine to host it. See https://www.geekrar.com/install-macos-high-sierra-on-virtualbox-2021/ for example. If that environment is faster, please let me know and I'll expand on that as an answer (or you can do so; it's OK to answer your own question).

Okay, I'll set this up as soon as I can and leave a comment later today. Thank you!

Check Activity Monitor if there is anything unexpected running on that Mac and using a lot of CPU (sort the Processes list by %CPU descending). Also have a look at the memory (also in Activity Monitor); maybe something is eating up your available RAM.

Do not discount that your perceptions adjust over time as well. "Fast" 7 or 8 years ago isn't fast today. Hardware can and does degrade as well. An old HDD could be a factor.

I have a macbook pro 2012 and it was painfully slow. Since replacing its HDD with a SSD it has become much faster. I don'r just mean booting time but in every thing.
Replace you HDD with a SSD and that should make it much faster.
